# Re-rendering the Activity in onRestart method in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, intellij-idea

**A little detail:**

I am using [**IntelliJ IDEA SQLite Database Viewer**](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/10/intellij-idea-13-eap-and-android-sqlite-database/) which connects to an installed and running app database and retrieves schema and data to show them on the IDE. It also allows you to upload the changes you make on it back to the device or emulator. *This info is not completely related to what I want but it is a kind of a side note about where I came to this problem from.*

**Problem:**

So when I make any changes like this, I need to remove any instance of my application from ***Recent Activities*** in order to completely restart it so that new changes can be reflected to UI. *Recent Activities appear after you hold your finger pressed on **Home** button for a couple of seconds.*

**What I want:**

But what I would like to do is that instead of removing any instances of my application to see the new changes in the database, I'd like to invalidate the whole view so that it renders itself and calls all the database related methods to get the fresh data.

**What my solution:**

My idea about how to accomplish this is something like this :

When I, let's say, click on the home button on the phone and re-open the app before it is completely being destroyed by Android OS, I guess Android re-runs it from `onRestart()` method rather than `onCreate()` method as described here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html but I may be wrong though. So if I put some logic in `onRestart()` method which forces the activity to get re-rendered with fresh data, then I can reach my goal.

But to reduce performance hit in the production, I want to read the attribute `android:debuggable="true"` attribute from `AndroidManifest.xml` file and perform this re-rendering when it is in true state. So when I publish the app, I can easily switch this to `false` for better performance.

I am open to new solution though.

**My Question:**

My question is that if anyone can tell me if I am on the right track for this problem and if yes, what kind of code I should put in `onRestart()` method in order to make the database data changes to get reflected to UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I found two ways to solve it:

**1.** Add the following to the intent when you start that Activity:

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

But this means that activity will never be restarted, even if a dialog displays and the user clicks the back-button.

**2.** Add this to the manifest for that Activity:

```
    android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

This works for what I want.

**OP's Comment:**

I felt the need to add this comment to answer I marked. This second option didn't solved my problem exactly how I want but still helped me. If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, then Shift + F10 will re-install your application to the device. Combination of this shortcut and the second option will solve the problem.

Comment: It looks really nice. But how would I do it within a check of `android:debuggable`?

Comment: You are supposed to remove `android:debuggable` before publishing it.  See: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html